# Android application / detect pictures

Tags: android, screenshot, detect

I'm programming an android application and I have problem when I try to detect a picture (ScreenShot) with Broadcast Receiver.
I did a class, CameraEventReceiver :

```
package studio.pomme.m.the33.Autres;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraEventReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.i("INFO", "Enter BroadcastReceiver");

        Cursor cursor = arg0.getContentResolver().query(arg1.getData(), null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String image_path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("_data"));
        Toast.makeText(arg0, "New Photo is Saved as : " + image_path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

And integer in the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />


<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/indice"
        android:label="33"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

        <receiver class = "studio.pomme.m.the33.Autres.CameraEventReceiver"
            android:name=".Autres.CameraEventReceiver"
            android:enabled="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="studio.pomme.m.the33.Level.Level25"  />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.action.Level25" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
</application>
```

The application starts here :

```
<activity
            android:name=".Level.Level25"
            android:screenOrientation ="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I hope i will that you find my problem...
Thank you !

Comment: But you haven't specified the problem...?!?

Comment: I would like detect picture in my "Level25" class. But nothing happen... I have not Log ..., not Toast... I dont know if somethings missing !